# css3 multiple animations with different durations

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Is it possible to give an element multiple animations with different durations using CSS3 animations?

What I want to have eventually is have the ball to keep rotating after finishing. I know I could do this with giving multiple classes. But I would like to avoid that to prevent messy amount of classes.

(the Fiddle might not work on other browsers than Chrome, I just rapidly hacked it together)

Fiddle example of what I have currently http://jsfiddle.net/cchsh6om/2/

Here's the CSS

```
div {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 46px;
    position: relative;
    background: #ddd;
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;

    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
span{
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 100px;
    left:48%;
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: 200px;  
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-left: 20px;  
        -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { 
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: 200px; 
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-left: 20px;  -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: 200px; 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-left: 20px; 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: 200px;
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-left: 20px; 
        transform:rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div><span>=</span></div>
```

Comment: Do you want an animation or a transition?

Comment: Animation :), so same as it already is but then have the rotation last longer

Comment: @BartBurg: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cchsh6om/1/) (only on Chrome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possibly, but your syntax is wrong. First of all, use short notation like `animation: horizontal linear 8s infinite` (for more information read this [acticle](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)). Then you you can apply multiple animations separated by comma on the same element:

```
animation:  horizontal linear 8s infinite,
              vertical ease-in-out 1.3s infinite alternate,
              blink linear .7s infinite alternate,
              rotation linear .4s infinite;
```

and define keyframes for each one of them:

```
@keyframes horizontal {
   from {left: 0;}
   to {left: 100%;} 
}
@keyframes vertical {
   from {top: 0;}
   to {top: 200px;} 
}
```

Finally, you can omit to `-moz` and `-ms` prefixes. `-webkit-animation` and `animation` works on all the modern browsers including mobile.

See my sample of multiple animation at [CodePen](http://codepen.io/rijii49/pen/wBeaLJ), i've tested it on many platforms.

Comment: Is it wrong or simply unnecessary long? Thanks a lot! Combining your answer with Harry's comment seems to be the solution to go for in the webapp I'm building :)